# Implicit Differentiation using 2 methods

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I want to implicitly differentiate this twice with respect to x (y is the dependent variable), (finding y''):
$$(xy)^3 = 4x$$
using the derivative rules we would get 
$$y'' = -\frac{3x^3y^3+8x - 3x^2y^4 + 12y}{3x^4y^3}$$

but, what if we assume $$xy = n$$

the equation would be $$n^3 = 4x$$

thus $$x = \frac{n^3}{4}$$

and since $$xy = n$$, $$y = \frac{4}{n^2}$$ right?

and after we found a direct relationship between x and n on a hand, and y and n on an other hand, can't we use the chain rule like this to find the second derivative? :

$$\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dn}  \frac{dn}{dx}$$

from the relationships i made, $$\frac{dn}{dx} = \frac{4}{3n^2}$$

and $$\frac{dy}{dn} = \frac{-8}{n^3}$$

so dy/dx = $$\frac{-32}{3n^5}$$ , and if we take the second derivative using the same way it would be $$\frac{-128}{9n^7}$$

is the second method correct? (substitution by n along with chain rule)

- somebody make the expressions size bigger here please, i don't know how

Comment: Instead of using line breaks to put a formula in display mode, use two dollar signs.  I changed the first couple, so you can see what I did.

Comment: thanks, done. better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get something different for the second differentiation:

$$y'' = \frac {d}{dx} (-\frac {32}{3} n^{-5}) = \frac {160}{3}n^{-6}\frac {dn}{dx} = \frac {640}{9n^8}$$

I think more straight forward would be:

$$x^3y^3 = 4x\\
y = 4^{\frac 13} x^{\frac {-2}3}\\
y' = -4^{\frac 13}\frac {2}{3} x^{\frac {-5}3}\\
y'' = 4^{\frac 13}\frac {10}{9} x^{\frac {-8}3}\\
y'' = \frac {10y}{9x^2}\\
$$

Does $\frac {640}{9n^8} = \frac {10y}{9x^2}$?

$$\frac {640n}{9n^9}\\
\frac {640xy}{9(xy)^9}\\
\frac {640xy}{9(4x)^3}\\
\frac {10y}{9x^2}$$

and what about $-\frac{3x^3y^3+8x - 3x^2y^4 + 12y}{3x^4y^3}$?

I haven't checked your work on the differentiation.

Applying $x^3y^3 = 4x$ where able I get $-\frac{12x + 8x - 12y + 12y}{12x^2}= \frac {10}{6} x$

It looks like something happened in the differentiation

Update

$$y''=-\frac{-18x^4y^6+24x^2y^3+32}{9x^6y^5}\\
x^2y^3 = 4
-\frac{-18(16)^6+24(4)+32}{9(4x)x^3y^2}\\
\frac{160}{9(4x)x^3y^2}\\
\frac{160y}{9(4x)x^3y^3}\\
\frac{160y}{9(4x)^2}\\
\frac {10y}{x^2}$$

Comment: Yep, your second derivative is right, I made a mistake while getting to it. Pretty cool, I think I'll differentiate it again from scratch and try substituting to see what do I get

Comment: Hmmm symbolab differentiated it like this: 

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(y\right)=-\frac{-18x^4y^6+24x^2y^3+32}{9x^6y^5}$$

i tried replacing x^3 y^3 with 4x but it gives me something else other than $$\frac{10y}{9x^2}$$

Comment: @StephenAlexander I have updated with my simplification of your derivative.

Comment: Great. This proves that both ways actually work which is amazing!